# Appcelerator Titanium - KitchenSink errors

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, titanium, appcelerator

I've tried to run the kitchensink example for appcelerator titanium (from their github link) and it errors, immensely! Any idea how to fix this to run the example?

Warning: Lots of errors

http://pastebin.com/2TBWnTQA

Comment: are you building to the Device or Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem, my workround was to uninstall the Titanium Appcelerator and re-install and the kitchen sink example started working.

Comment: just updating the sdk to ios 4.3. Will try your fix after ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are using the github link. I am running the latest KitchenSink sample for Android and is working fine. Please delete the build folder and build log file before running. Please paste the entire console error log for more information